# server responds with 405 error even with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'?

Tags: javascript, cors

SO my graphql api is at https://gpbaculio-tributeapp.herokuapp.com/graphql I configured the uploaded, headers like this:

```
const fetchQuery = (operation, variables) => {
  return fetch('/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: operation.text,
      variables,
    }),
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
}
```

I have read from MDN.

> For requests without credentials, the server may specify "*" as a
>   wildcard, thereby allowing any origin to access the resource.

So I am trying to publish the app in codepen, and this is my error:

> Failed to load https://gpbaculio-tributeapp.herokuapp.com/graphql:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://s.codepen.io'

Why is it telling me it doesn't pass 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers?

Is there something wrong with my headers config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting **cors** options and **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** headers in server side.

```
const graphQLServer = express();
const corsOptions = {
    origin(origin, callback) {
        callback(null, true);
    },
    credentials: true
};
graphQLServer.use(cors(corsOptions));
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
}
graphQLServer.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

This may help you

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the header in your request (in the client). The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header needs to be set on the server-side, and when you make a request, the response should contain that header.

The reason behind this header is that not every webpage can query every third-party domain. Being able to set this header from the request would defeat that whole point.

Answer (score 1):

CORS specification states, that requests for resources are "preflighted" with HTTP OPTIONS request, and reply headers for that OPTIONS must contain header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

you might check it with curl:

```
$ curl -I -X OPTIONS https://gpbaculio-tributeapp.herokuapp.com/graphql
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Allow: GET, POST
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 97
Date: Sat, 23 Sep 2017 11:24:39 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

Add OPTION handler with needed header, so your server answers:

```
$ curl -I -X OPTIONS https://example.localhost/
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx/1.4.7
Date: Sat, 23 Sep 2017 11:27:51 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the browser's cross-origin problem.

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should be return by the server's response, and the header means the origin domain that can access to the API.

The client's request often take a header `Origin`, it's value is the current host address, like, `www.example.com`.

The values of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must contain the value of `Origin` means that the origin can access this API service. And then the browser will continue the request. If not, the browser will cancel the request.

[image]

More infomation, refre to CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: but even though I have tried Access-Control-Allow-Origin:s.codepen.io it still returns error?

Comment: The CORS solution for cross origin need the server and the client cooperate to config the solution. And the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is just one of the all operations. More infomation, refre to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS